# How do I extract a certain letter n#s before a specific pattern in a data frame in Python?

Tags: python, regex, extract

I have a column in a dataframe that lists DNA sequences, I would like to do the following two things. Below is an example of the data set

```
d = [['ampC','tacggtctggctgctatcctgacagttgtcacgctgattggtgtcgttacaatctaacgcAtcgccaatgtaaatccggcccgcc'], ['yifL','acttcataaagagtcgctaaacgcttgcttttacgtcttctcctgcgatgatagaaagcaGaaagcgatgaactttacaggcaat'],['glyW','tcaaaagtggtgaaaaatatcgttgactcatcgcgccaggtaagtagaatgcaacgcatcGaacggcggcactgattgccagacg']]
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns = ['gene','Sequence'])
```

| gene | Sequence |
| --- | --- |
| ampC | tacggtctggctgctatcctgacagttgtcacgctgattggtgtcgttacaatctaacgcAtcgccaatgtaaatccggcccgcc |
| yifL | acttcataaagagtcgctaaacgcttgcttttacgtcttctcctgcgatgatagaaagcaGaaagcgatgaactttacaggcaat |
| glyW | tcaaaagtggtgaaaaatatcgttgactcatcgcgccaggtaagtagaatgcaacgcatcGaacggcggcactgattgccagacg |

1. Extract the capital letter and everything before it. With `str.extract(r"(.*?)[A-Z]+", expand=True)` I can get everything before the capital letter but I need help figuring out how to get the capital letter as well.

Example of what I'm trying to get for ampC: tacggtctggctgctatcctgacagttgtcacgctgattggtgtcgttacaatctaacgcA

2. How to extract the 16th letter before the capital letter.

Example of what I'm trying to get for the following 3 genes:

| gene | letter |
| --- | --- |
| ampC | c |
| yifL | g |
| glyW | t |

[c, g, t]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression is *almost* what you need. Just move the capital letters inside the group. Try with:

```
df["substring"] = df["Sequence"].str.extract(r"(.*?[A-Z])")[0]
df["letter"] = df["Sequence"].str.extract(r"(.*?[A-Z])")[0].str[-17]

>>> df[["gene", "letter"]]
   gene letter
0  ampC      c
1  yifL      g
2  glyW      t
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```py
df["SubSequence"] = df["Sequence"].str.extract(r'^(.*?[A-Z])')
df["letter"] = df["Sequence"].str.extract(r'^[acgt]*([acgt])[acgt]{15}[A-Z]')
```